# XSS attack from url get variable

Tags: javascript, php

I have a site fetch data from database and create a links to next page

The links page will required `page_id` and it will display title on url bar

```
<a href=example.php?page=2&title=foo">click</a>
```

The URL will display:

```
example.php?page=2&title=foo
```

`page_id` will be number only but title can be anything.

My questions are:

- What if user save `javascript:alert()` into title?
- Will it run script from URL?
- Is there anything else I should take care of?

Comment: @AmalMurali `Cross Site Scripting` attack

Comment: Sounds like some sort of "behind you back" attack... Regarding OP question : have you checked the two billions threads about xss and sql injection on SO ?

Comment: Ben and I edited it at the same time :)

Comment: How long does it take to check it by yourself? ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser shouldn't and doesn't (at least IE11 doesn't) execute javascript in the `onclick` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

you should use:

- urlencode to encode query parameters,
- htmlspecialchars to escape    content typed by user inside html
- binding parameters to sql statements to avoid sql injection
  (http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)